# How to have multiple source dirs?

Tags: c++, makefile

After doing some research, I was able to found the following makefile to compile every `cpp` file in my project and place every object files in the `obj` directory. However, it still doesn't work. I have two directories, one called `src` and another one called `lib`. I'm not able to make it work for both of these directories. Any help?

```
TARGET   = app
CC       = c++
CFLAGS   = -std=c++2a -Wall -I.
LINKER   = c++
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
SRCDIR   = src lib
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = .

# SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
SOURCES  := $(wildcard */*.cpp ) # Match every c++ file
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

It will compile every file inside the `src` directory but it will ignore the `lib` directory. Can someone read it and explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does this work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below code which will help you to compile from src and lib directory all C++ files:

```
TARGET   = app
CC       = c++
CFLAGS   = -std=c++2a -Wall -I.
LINKER   = c++
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
# SRCDIR   = src lib
# I created a separate variable for src and lib path
SRC_PATH =./src/
LIB_PATH =./lib/
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = .

# Collect all cpp files from src and lib folder
SOURCES  := $(shell find $(SRC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) -type f -name '*.cpp' ) 
# Collect all headers from src and lib folder
INCLUDES := $(shell find $(SRC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) -type f -name '*.h' )
# Get all object files from SOURCES
OBJECTS   := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o,   $(notdir $(SOURCES)))
rm       = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(LIB_PATH)/%.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

You could also do it in below way without creating separate variable for src and lib:

```
TARGET   = app
CC       = c++
CFLAGS   = -std=c++2a -Wall -I.
LINKER   = c++
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
SRCDIR   = src lib
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = .

# Collect all cpp files from src and lib folder
SOURCES  := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name '*.cpp' ) 
# Collect all headers from src and lib folder
INCLUDES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name '*.h' )
# Get all object files from SOURCES
OBJECTS   := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o,   $(notdir $(SOURCES)))
rm       = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"

vpath %.cpp $(wildcard *)
```